# Why does Prisma want to delete my existing tables?

Tags: node.js, prisma

I set up a new db and manually created a table in it, but when I try to make my prisma model `prisma migrate dev`, it wants to delete the table I created. I don't want this. I try `--create-only`, but it doesn't work.
my model

`npx prisma migrate dev --create-only` and `npx prisma migrate dev`

It does not touch the tables I added manually and does not disrupt existing tables.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzlW9.png)

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

```
model noe_pdks_yer {
  id                        Int                         @id @default(autoincrement())
  nva_alan                  String?
  bit_calisma_saati_uygula  Boolean?
  nva_fabrika               String?
  createdAt                 DateTime                    @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt                 DateTime?                   @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  kapilar                   noe_pdks_kapilar[]
  noe_pdks_personel_son_yer noe_pdks_personel_son_yer[]
}

model noe_pdks_kapilar {
  id                   Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  yer                  noe_pdks_yer           @relation(fields: [int_yer_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  int_yer_id           Int
  nva_kapi_code        String                 @unique
  bit_giris_cikis      Boolean?
  int_device_mod       Int?
  createdAt            DateTime               @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt            DateTime?              @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  noe_pdks_log_kapi    noe_pdks_log_kapi[]
  noe_pdks_log_kard    noe_pdks_log_kard[]
  noe_pdks_giris_cikis noe_pdks_giris_cikis[]
}

model noe_pdks_log_kapi {
  id          Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  kapi        noe_pdks_kapilar @relation(fields: [int_kapi_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  int_kapi_id Int
  nva_ip      String?
  nva_version String?
  int_wifi    Int?
  createdAt   DateTime         @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt   DateTime?        @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}

model noe_pdks_log_kapi_tanimsiz {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  kapi_code   String    @unique
  nva_ip      String?
  nva_version String?
  int_wifi    Int?
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt   DateTime? @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}

model noe_pdks_log_kard {
  id               Int               @id @default(autoincrement())
  kapi             noe_pdks_kapilar? @relation(fields: [int_kapi_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  int_kapi_id      Int?
  kapi_code        String?
  nva_sicilkodu    String?
  nva_sicilismi    String?
  nva_durum        String?
  rf_id            String?
  bit_izin_verildi Boolean?
  createdAt        DateTime          @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt        DateTime?         @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}

model noe_pdks_giris_cikis {
  id               Int              @id @default(autoincrement())
  nva_aktifpasif   String?
  bit_onay         Boolean?
  kapi             noe_pdks_kapilar @relation(fields: [int_kapi_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  int_kapi_id      Int
  nva_durum        String?
  nva_zaman        String?
  nva_sicilkodu    String?
  nva_sicilismi    String?
  rf_id            String?
  bit_izin_verildi Boolean?
  createdAt        DateTime         @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt        DateTime?        @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}

model noe_pdks_personel_son_yer {
  id             Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  yer            noe_pdks_yer @relation(fields: [int_yer_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  int_yer_id     Int
  nva_aktifpasif String?
  nva_sicilkodu  String?
  nva_sicilismi  String?
  rf_id          String?
  createdAt      DateTime     @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt      DateTime?    @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}

model noe_pdks_personel_listesi {
  id                                Int                                @id @default(autoincrement())
  nva_aktifpasif                    String                             @default("A")
  nva_sicilkodu                     String?
  nva_sirketkodu                    String?
  nva_adi                           String?
  nva_soyadi                        String?
  nva_mail                          String?
  nva_gsm                           String?
  rf_id                             String?
  nva_izinli_kapilar                String?
  createdAt                         DateTime                           @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt                         DateTime?                          @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  noe_pdks_personel_calisma_listesi noe_pdks_personel_calisma_listesi?
}

model noe_pdks_personel_calisma_listesi {
  id                 Int                       @id @default(autoincrement())
  nva_aktifpasif     String                    @default("A")
  personel           noe_pdks_personel_listesi @relation(fields: [person_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction)
  nva_vardiya        String?
  person_id          Int                       @unique
  giris_tolerans_alt String?
  giris_tolerans_ust String?
  girissaati         String?
  cikis_tolerans_alt String?
  cikis_tolerans_ust String?
  cikissaati         String?
  yemeksuresi        String?
  createdAt          DateTime                  @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
  updatedAt          DateTime?                 @default(dbgenerated("GETDATE()")) @db.DateTime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table inside the prisma model and then do `npx prisma migrate dev`.

If you want to create a table directly inside the database like you did, and then move it to prisma model, you need to use prisma introspection tool.

Check the docs before using introspection
https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-schema/introspection

Pick one of those ways and then try to create a table by that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think the problem is that I cannot delete the history. When I do npx prisma migrate dev, it finds diff. Even if I use prisma db pull and prisma generate for existing tables, I still get the same error. It says migration diff, even though I deleted the migration files and table.